# How can I convert all SMALLINT columns in PostgreSQL database to BOOLEAN?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database, postgresql

I migrated my Django website database **from MySQL to PostgreSQL** using a third party tool **pgloader**. But since MySQL stores **BOOLEAN** data as **TINYINT** by default(at least with Django), it got converted to **SMALLINT** in PostgreSQL. Now Django is showing error that **smallint is being treated as boolean**. Due to this, I want to convert all smallint columns to boolean. Is there a single command to convert all columns in all tables in a single database to required type? If I have to perform the operation separately for each table, that's OK too.

**EDIT:**

Column structure:

`public            | smallint                 | default '1'::smallint`

Here **public** is column name, **smallint** it's type and has it **default value of '1'**.

The code I used:

```
utkarsh@utkarsh-Lenovo-G580:~$ psql -d thakurani -U utkarsh
Password for user utkarsh: 
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

thakurani=# alter table topics_topic alter COLUMN public type boolean using(public::text::boolean);                             ERROR:  default for column "public" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
thakurani=# alter table topics_topic alter COLUMN public type text using(public::text);
ALTER TABLE
thakurani=# alter table topics_topic alter COLUMN public type boolean using(public::boolean);
ERROR:  default for column "public" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
thakurani=# ALTER TABLE topics_topic ALTER COLUMN public TYPE boolean USING CASE WHEN public = '0' THEN FALSE WHEN public = '1' THEN TRUE END;
ERROR:  default for column "public" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
thakurani=#
```

Comment: have you tried to simply change the type in the model and let `migrations` do the job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need double cast - first cast int as text, then text as boolean

here is an example:

```
t=# create table s181(i smallint default 1::smallint);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s181 values (0),(1);
INSERT 0 2
t=# alter table s181 alter COLUMN i drop default;
ALTER TABLE
t=# alter table s181 alter COLUMN i type boolean using(i::text::boolean);
ALTER TABLE
t=# alter table s181 alter COLUMN i set default true;
ALTER TABLE
t=# \d s181
       Table "public.s181"
 Column |  Type   |  Modifiers
--------+---------+--------------
 i      | boolean | default true
```

Comment: This is giving me an error : ERROR:  default for column "public" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean

Comment: I am able to convert to type text, but converting from text to boolean gives me the same error as before.

Comment: please update your post with existing table structure and exact command then.

Comment: I edited the post with the commands and column structure. I think the problem is occuring because of default value set to '1'.  But don't know why exactly.

Comment: @UtkarshGarg updated to reconcile with your situation